# Custom Annotation with a button. didSelectAnnotaionView does not seem to get called

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am having a problem with my didSelectAnnotationView getting called when I use a custom annotation view. I was hoping someone might be able to take a look and help me with what I am missing.

I actually want a method to get called when the user touches the button show in the screenshot of my custom annotation which can be seen below.  I was trying to make that the calloutAccessoryView, but I am doing something wrong.  Please if anyone has done custom annotation views that a user can click on please see if you can help!!  This is driving me crazy.  I think I have posted the relevant info here, if not ask and I will edit my post.

**I am adding a custom annotation like this:**

```
LocationObject * obj = [m_MyObject.marLocations objectAtIndex:page];
obj.title =@"A";
[mvMapView addAnnotation:obj];
```

**My Location object used above is defined like this:**

```
// Location Object
@interface LocationObject : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * practicename;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * mapaddress1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * city;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * state;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * zip;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * phone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * fax;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end // End Location Object
```

**My viewForAnnotation does this:**

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        [map.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"annotationViewID";
    ViewDirectionsAnnotationView * annotationView = [[ViewDirectionsAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    int page = floor((svOfficesScrollView.contentOffset.x - svOfficesScrollView.frame.size.width / 2) / svOfficesScrollView.frame.size.width) + 1;
    LocationObject * obj = [m_DentistObject.marLocations objectAtIndex:page];
    double dLatitude = [obj.latitude doubleValue];
    double dLongitude = [obj.longitude doubleValue];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(dLatitude, dLongitude);
    ((LocationObject*)annotation).coordinate = coordinate;
    annotationView.lbPracticeName.text = obj.practicename;
    annotationView.lbStreet.text = obj.address1;
    NSString * sCityStateZip = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@", obj.city, obj.state, obj.zip];
    annotationView.lbCityStateZip.text = sCityStateZip;
    annotationView.lbPhoneNumber.text = obj.phone;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = (UIButton *)[annotationView viewWithTag:1]; //[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    return annotationView;
}
```

**And my Annotation View is like this:**

```
@interface ViewDirectionsAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D    coordinate;
    NSString        * title;
    NSString        * subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView * loadedView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel  * lbPracticeName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel  * lbStreet;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel  * lbCityStateZip;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel  * lbPhoneNumber;

@end
```

And the xib for the above view looks like this:

[image]

But, my didSelectAnnotationView never gets called. Can anybody explain what I am missing?

Please, any help is appreciated this has been driving me nuts.  I could have it completely wrong, but the custom view does appear so I think I am close.

Thanks for the help!!

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention about the delegate. I have checked the delegate many times and believe I have it right.  In the ViewController .h file where the mapView is, I have the  and I set [mapView setDelegate:self]  In that same .m file is where I have implemented the viewForAnnotation method and didSelectAnnotationView.  The viewForAnnotation gets called but not the other.

One more interesting piece of information is that if I click (touch) just below my custom annotation then didSelectAnnotationView does get called. I guess now I am more confused!!

UPDATE #2:

My xib is loaded this way:

In my viewForAnnotation I call initWithAnnotation.  That method is as follows:

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DirectionsAnnotation" owner:self options:nil];
        if (loadedView)
        {
            [loadedView setFrame:CGRectMake(-(loadedView.frame.size.width/2), -(loadedView.frame.size.height), loadedView.frame.size.width, loadedView.frame.size.height)];
            [self addSubview:loadedView];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: How is the xib being loaded exactly and are you setting the annotation view's frame?  An unrelated note regarding the code in viewForAnnotation: much of it is inefficient and unnecessarily complex.

Comment: I do not do anything with the annotation views frame. and can you explain what is complex?  if you are referring to my code I am open to any suggestions.  I have updated my post to show how I load the xib.

Comment: Try setting the annotation view's frame to the size of the xib.  The xib may be larger than the default frame and touches outside are not handled.  In viewForAnnotation, the unnecessary complexity is in "finding" the annotation by calculating page etc.  The annotation is already given as the parameter to the method -- you don't need to find it or set its coordinate.

Comment: Sorry, when I updated my post I noticed that I set the frame there.  You can see the code... does it look right?  Ahh, yes, I noticed that and corrected that already!!!  Thanks for pointing it out though, makes me feel good that I did the right thing!!

Comment: Perhaps one of the views in the nib is capturing the touch? My best guess is `loadedView`, try unchecking "user interaction enabled" in the nib.

Comment: @LilMoke, the code is setting loadedView's frame but not the annotation view itself.  After the addSubview, try `self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, loadedView.frame.size.width, loadedView.frame.size.height);`.

Comment: LOL, I just noticed that myself because you mentioned the frame I checked the frame in my viewForAnnotation and noticed it was coming back as 0, 0, 0, 0 so I thought i might try something like that.  Stay tuned I will do it right now!!! -:)

Comment: Ok, different results... it works now when I click the button, however, my annotation is much bigger than the xib, maybe about 2x.  Why would that be?

Comment: Actually, since you are offsetting the loadedView frame, you might have to just do self.frame = loadedView.frame;.  You can set the view's color (self.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];) so you can see where the touches will work and then figure out the right frame.

Comment: good idea, i will try that... BTW, thank you sooo much for the help, I have been struggling with this for hours upon hours.  You are a godsend!!!!  I will try your ideas now... thanks again!!! :-)

Comment: Worked perfect, turns out the xib was set to autosize. removed that and everything was prefect. Thank you for all your help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The view which is displaying your MapView needs to be set as your delegate.

Where is your didSelectAnnotationView? Make sure that it implements the delegate protocol. E.g.

```
@interface MyView : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
...
@end
```

Then somewhere else...

```
[mapView setDelegate:myView];
```

Comment: The view where I create the map view is a ViewController and set as the delegate and I do have the <MKMapViewDelegate> in my header file for that view.  I have checked that a hundred times, I think it must be some thing else.  Any other suggestions?